# procedure problem

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ora-00984

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE XXB_RJT_HEADER_PROCEURE 
  (
    V_PROD_ID  IN NUMBER,
    V_WARE_ID  IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.WAREHOUSE_ID% TYPE,
    V_PAY_METH IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.PAYMENT_METHOD% TYPE,
    V_PAY_STAT IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.PAYMENT_STATUS% TYPE,
    V_ORD_ID   IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.ORDER_ID% TYPE,
    V_ORD_DT   IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.ORDER_DATE% TYPE )
AS
  V_PROD_NM VARCHAR2(50);
  V_WAR_NM  VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  SELECT PRODUCT_CAT
  INTO V_PROD_NM
  FROM xxb_rjt_inventory
  WHERE XXB_RJT_INVENTORY.product_id= V_prod_id;
  SELECT WAREHOUSE_NAME
  INTO V_WAR_NM
  FROM xxb_rjt_inventory
  WHERE XXB_RJT_INVENTORY.product_id= V_prod_id;

  INSERT
  INTO XXB_RJT_HEADER
    (                  /*second error*/
      warehouse_id,
      PAYMENT_METHOD,
      payment_status,
      product_name,
      order_id,
      wareshouse_name,
      order_date
    )
    VALUES
    (
      V_warehouse_id,
      v_pay_meth,  /*First error*/
      V_pay_stat,
      V_prod_nm,
      V_ord_id,
      V_war_nm,
      V_ord_dt
    );



END XXB_RJT_HEADER_PROCEURE;
```

when i compile this i get the following errors

```
Error(37,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Error(24,65530): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: As a hint, the CREATE OR REPLACE bit doesn't count when determining which line an error is being reported for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"V_warehouse_id" is no declared anywhere.

Comment: thx a million what a silly mistake yet was wasting an hr behind it thx once again

Answer (score 2):

Your ORA-00984 error [means](http://ora-00984.ora-code.com/):

> A column name was used in an
>   expression where it is not permitted,
>   such as in the VALUES clause of an
>   INSERT statement.

Check the VALUES part of the INSERT to be sure none of the arguments are columns.

Once you fix that, see if the other error goes away. "PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" seems to appear after there's already another error.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite is in something like (untested):

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE XXB_RJT_HEADER_PROCEURE 
  (
    V_PROD_ID  IN xxb_rjt_inventory.product_id%type,
    V_WARE_ID  IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.WAREHOUSE_ID% TYPE,
    V_PAY_METH IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.PAYMENT_METHOD% TYPE,
    V_PAY_STAT IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.PAYMENT_STATUS% TYPE,
    V_ORD_ID   IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.ORDER_ID% TYPE,
    V_ORD_DT   IN XXB_RJT_HEADER.ORDER_DATE% TYPE )
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT
  INTO XXB_RJT_HEADER
    (                  
      warehouse_id,
      PAYMENT_METHOD,
      payment_status,
      product_name,
      order_id,
      wareshouse_name,
      order_date
    )
    select 
      V_ware_id,
      v_pay_meth,  
      V_pay_stat,
      product_cat,
      V_ord_id,
      warehouse_name,
      V_ord_dt
    from xxb_rjt_inventory
    where product_id= V_prod_id;

END XXB_RJT_HEADER_PROCEURE;
```

This means two less sql statements and two less variables to declare. Also change the name of the procedure, you write proceure instead of procedure. I also changed the type of the first parameter of your procedure.